# Detecting directories opened by java.lang.Class.getResourceAsStream()

Tags: java, io

Assuming the following resources are in the class path:

```
/res/image/logo.png
/res/image/splash.png
```

Then it is possible to get an `InputStream` for logo.png using:

```
SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/image/logo.png");
```

If you ask for a resource that does not exist, `getResourceAsStream()` returns null.

However, if you ask for a resource that's really a directory, you don't get null or an exception: you actually get a `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`.  Having dumped the bytes from this stream, it appears to be a listing of the resources in that directory (one per line).

So:

```
SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/image");
```

Gives a `ByteArrayInputStream` which when dumped contains:

```
logo.png
splash.png
```

Is there a reliable way to identify that the resource opened by `getResourceAsStream()` was really a directory?  Or some other way to access classpath resources, such that this is possible?  (Can it be done with `getResource()` in some way, perhaps?)

UPDATE:

Just out of interest, I called `getResource()` and dumped the URL of a 'resource' that I know doesn't exist as a file on disk (in this case `/java/util/List.class`).  Here's what I got:

```
jar:file:/C:/projects/<my_proj>/env/jdk/jre/lib/rt.jar!/java/util/List.class
```

But for `/java/util` I got:

```
null
```

So the `null` could be taken as an (admittedly indirect, perhaps not reliable) indication that the 'resource' was a directory *if* the resource's URL wasn't a 'file:' resource.  And if it was the solution suggested using `File.isDirectory()` could be used.

I think this hack will work.  I'm not sure that I'll actually use it in real code!  ;-)

Comment: This is an interesting question, but do you have a practical application in mind, or is it just academic interest?

Comment: Yes - I have a practical application (and some failing unit tests).  I've defined a (minimal) `Store` interface that hides various kinds of 'file system'.  For example, in our online help system, I want to provide the help servlet with a store of help files.  It should not care whether the store is a directory of files, a zip/jar file, or a subset of the resources on the classpath.  I have a suite of unit tests that check the the four implementations I've written behave the same.  One test asserts you can't open a directory in the store, but this fails for the resource-based implementation.

Comment: Have you looked at Spring's resource and scanning support? I don't know the details of your use case, but it might already have the functionality you need.

Answer (score 2):

Testing a non-`null` result of `getResource()` for being a directory is quite simple: just check whether its [path](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#getPath%28%29) ends with `"/"` ( a slash).

If you distrust that simple check you would have to implement checks for each protocol individually. For `file:` URLs there is a safe way:

```
URL url = Foo.class.getResource(".");
if(url.getProtocol().equals("file"))
{
  boolean dir=new File(url.toURI()).isDirectory();
}
```

For others it is not so obvious. Some protocols might not even have the concept of a directory (or the distinction between files and directories). For `JAR` files you usually get a `null` as typically `JAR` files do not contain entries for directories.

Answer (score 1):

getResource() gives an URL. Inspect that URL, if it starts with "file://", then you can extract the file name, and call `new File(name).isDirectory()`.

If it does not start with "file://", then it is behind a web server and there is no standard way to determine if the resource is a directory.

Appendix

try to add "/." or "/.." to the URL - if the denoted resource exists, the URL refers to a directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect whether an `InputStream` is a file or directory by it's class. If it is a file, it will be a "BufferedInputStream" and a directory will be a "ByteArrayInputStream".

```
public boolean isDirectory(InputStream is) {
  return is.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("ByteArrayInputStream");
}

public boolean isFile(InputStream is) {
  return is.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("BufferedInputStream");
}
```

For example:

```
InputStream is = SomeClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/res/image");
boolean isDirectory = isDirectory(is); //true
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know there is no way from getResourceAsStream but  you check it if it is a file or directory anytime by  get the URL using `getResource`,then get the path then `new File(path).isDirectory()` and `new File(path).isFile()`

Comment: Not is it's inside my applications .jar file, or some other .jar file in my application's classpath.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
URL resource = getClass().getResource("/res/image");
File folder = new File(new URI(resource.getPath()).getPath());
if(folder.isDirectory()) {
    // do something
}
```